# How to set CSS class or style in forms for confluence?

Tags: css, forms, confluence

I have referred this website https://www.adaptavist.com/doco/display/F4C so that I can implement forms for confluence.
I have created basic forms and captured the output in a response table. My next step is to use CSS class and styling to improve the overall UI and how the forms should handle some UI logic.

I tried exploring the documentation link shared above but did not find anything related to CSS class or Style. There is no example or steps to explain how you can achieve that feature. I can clearly see that they have fields like CSS Class and CSS Style, but no explanation of how to achieve it.

If needed, I can share screenshots of my forms.

What I want is steps or example to achieve CSS functionality in Forms for Confluence? 
Honestly starting point which I can use to build a good and effective CSS logic for my Forms for Confluence.
Any help is welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Amey Kelekar

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is better to ask questions about Atlassian related products and 3rd party plugins at [Atlassian community](https://community.developer.atlassian.com).

I cannot help much with Adaptavist's forms, but could certainly help with the "forms plugin" we develop, called [ConfiForms for Atlassian Confluence](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1211860/confiforms-data-forms-workflows?hosting=datacenter&tab=overview) (where you can easily define own CSS styles, conditional styles and much more)

Comment: Seems more like a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the box (more an Atlassian Community contributor) - thanks for pointing this out.